# How to upload image as base64 in django-rest? i converted but. image still saves as regular image

Tags: python, django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

so here i am trying to convert it and then passing to the post request.
Although i can send the image and the image is being converted the string it does not save into the database or send into the API

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        #image_to_encode = validated_data['image']
        #encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_to_encode.read() )
        #print(encoded_string)
        return Evento.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

this is part from my serializer

Answer (score 0):

When you encode the image to a string you'll need to set that string on your validated data under the appropriate field name, i.e.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        image_to_encode = validated_data['image']
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_to_encode.read() )
        validated_data['encoded_image'] = encoded_string
        return Evento.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute '_committed'

Comment: This error is probably because the field on the model is a `models.ImageField`, if you want to store the image as an encoded string you should use a `models.CharField` or `models.TextField`.  Note that I used a different field ("encoded_image") in my answer for the encoded image text.

Comment: I decided not to use base64, still getting same error. However, I managed to serve the files using the rest documentation